# How do I use the {% url %} tag in a library app?

Tags: python, django

How do I use the `{% url .. %}` template tag in a "library" app to create a link to the library-app's own views?

Given a site with `mysite/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='mysite')),
]
```

and an app with `myapp/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^mylib/', include('mylib.urls', namespace='mylib')),
]
```

and the library app with `mylib/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^commands/$', views.commands, name='list-commands'),
    url(r'^command-1/$', views.command_1, name='command-1'),
]
```

where the `views.commands` view displays a template that should contain a link to `/myapp/mylib/command-1/`, ie. `mylib/templates/mylib/list-commands.html`

```
<a href='{% url "command-1" %}'>command-1</a>
```

It will of course work if I change it to:

```
{% url "mysite:mylib:command-1" %}
```

but the author of mylib doesn't know about neither mysite or myapp...?

I have a feeling I've misunderstood something basic...

Answer (score 1):

in your myapps/urls add:

```
app_name = #enter app_name here[say x]
```

then use

```
{% url 'x:command-1' %}
```

read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/